# A question about javascript data processing

Tags: javascript

for example :

```
var array2 = [{"A":1},{"B":2},{"C":3},{"D":4},...];
```

How to get specified range data(like 11~20 data)?

Comment: what is the expected outcome?

Comment: Where is your try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for this:

```js
var array2 = [{"A":1},{"B":2},{"C":3},{"D":4},{"E":5},{"F":6},{"G":7},{"H":8},{"I":9},{"J":10},{"K":11},{"L":12},{"M":13},{"N":14},{"O":15},{"P":16},{"Q":17},{"R":18},{"S":19},{"T":20},{"U": 21}];

var rangeMin = 11;
var rangeMax = 20;
var result = array2.filter((item) => item[Object.keys(item)[0]] >= rangeMin && item[Object.keys(item)[0]] <= rangeMax);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is always in ascending order, increasing by one each object, you could use `.slice()`, which will give you a portion of your array from a starting index to an ending index:

```js
const arr = [{"A":1},{"B":2},{"C":3},{"D":4},{"E":5}];

const getValuesInRange = (arr, x, y) => 
  arr.slice(x-1, y);

console.log(getValuesInRange(arr, 2, 4));
```

Alternatively, could use `Object.values()` to get the numeric value from each object and use that with `.filter` to only keep those objects where the numeric value is in between your given range:

```js
const arr = [{"A":1},{"B":2},{"C":3},{"D":4},{"E":5}];

const getValuesInRange = (arr, x, y) => 
  arr.filter(obj => {
    const n =  Object.values(obj).pop();
    return x <= n && n <= y;
  });

console.log(getValuesInRange(arr, 2, 4));
```